# AVPlayer not playing in background watchOS - Swift

Tags: swift, background, avplayer, watchos

I'm in trouble with my watchOS app. I correctly created the code for play a stream through a URL on Apple Watch and playing it on watch speaker. The problem is that: when I'm moving the wrist down the player is pausing.

In my target, watch extension I enabled as Capability: Background modes and put the thick on Audio.

The code for initialize the player is this:

```
do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, policy: .default, options: .duckOthers)
        //try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
    }catch {
        self.playButton.setTitle("ERROR")
        print("CATCHED ERROR", error)
    }

    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    }
    catch {
        self.playButton.setTitle("ERROR")
        print ("audiosession cannot be activated")
    }

    //Context is receiving the URL from RadioController
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(radioData.u ?? "")") else {
        return
    }

    let asset  = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
    item   = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: nil)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

    player.play()
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the `.longFormAudio` policy

Comment: But, if I'll use .longFormAudio it will automatically pop-up the bluetooth pairing and I'll not be able to hear from the watch speaker, isn't it?

Comment: That's your option, play audio through the watch speaker when the app is active with the wrist raised or use Bluetooth.

Comment: So basically, if the wrist is down it cannot play through watchOS Speaker but if policy will be .longFormAudio it can play via Bluetooth even though the wrist is down?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The fact is that if I'm enabling .longFormAudio and I'm turning the wrist, the audio is stopping. So something is missing.

Comment: @PietroMessineo have you been able to figure this out? To play audio in the background through the watch's speaker?

Comment: @MichalŠrůtek Unfortunately no... There is no way so far. With watchOS 8 they will enable AlwaysOn app to work, so it will be worth to try... But I believe it will be supported by only Apple Watch S5 and newest

Comment: @PietroMessineo but how Calm was able to implement this?